# (JNI) Get Java method's memory address with GetMethodID

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface, reverse-engineering

How can I get the Memory location of the method I have the JNI MethodID of?

I want to hook or manipulate Java Methods by using JNI because as everybody knows, JVM relocates such methods so static pointers to methods can't be used.

So I'm using C++ and JNI to get a MethodID out of the JVM.

The MethodID can be casted to an Integer, which is a hexadecimal memory address.

I already found out, that at the memory location of MethodID, there is a pointer to a HEAP address. This heap address points to a

"jvm.dll.53A14DE8 Method : Metadata : MetaspaceObj"

(That's what my reverse tool "ReClass.NET" says)

So that jvm.dll.xxx Method got some function pointers, but these can't be the Method because they consist of 3 bytes (too small) or are really too big (30 instructions+).
The Method I want to find only returns a float of 1.0

That's the jvm.dll.xxx Method in ReClass.NET:
[image: That's the jvm.dll.xxx Method in ReClass.NET]

Or is there any other way of natively hooking/manipulating Java Methods without JVMTI?

Comment: You could look at how JNA (https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) gets the addresses for callbacks

Comment: Why not JVM TI? This is the right way (I'd say, the *only* way) to manipulate Java methods.

Comment: I'm trying to find out a alternative way of manipulating by getting the address of a method. JNA and JVM TI are patched and will crash what I want to manipulate.

Comment: What do you mean by "JVM TI is patched and will crash"? This is the essential part of the standard JVM, and should be available just like JNI.

Comment: I inject one DLL into the target process. I tried to use JVM TI Agents and JNA but the process got some protection causing crashes, so I can’t use them. I know that my way is possible, but I‘m stuck at reversing.

Comment: Again: there is no such thing as a "method address". Java method may have an address of the bytecode, and multiple (possibly zero) compiled entries. Even if you patch them all, this still does not guarantee the behavior changes, as the method may have already been inlined into some other compiled methods. The latter is especially likely for a simple method like "return 1.0". In this case you'll have to find all the call sites of the method, recursively patch them and so on... In theory, this is possible, but this is a huge research far beyond your original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't hook Java methods like you do with native methods, i.e. replace machine code right in the memory.

`jmethodID` is an opaque reference to a Java method. It may be implemented differently in different JVMs, or even in different versions of the same JVM. For example, the internal representation of `jmethodID` has changed between JDK 7 and JDK 8 with the advent of Metaspace.

Now, in HotSpot JVM, `jmethodID` is a pointer to the `Method` structure in Metaspace. It is *not* the code of Java method, but rather an internal structure representing a method inside JVM.

Note that Java method initially does not have any machine code at all - instead, JVM interprets its bytecode. Due to JIT compilation, recompilation or deoptimization the machine code for a method may appear, change or disappear completely. Also, a method may have multiple JIT-compiled versions at the same time. That's why traditional hooking techniques cannot be applied to Java methods. Furthermore, a method may be inlined into other JIT-compiled methods, and in this case `jmethodID` will be useless at all.

However, there is a *standard* technique for manipulating Java methods - the [bytecode instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#bci). It is available through the *standard* API, namely, [RetransformClasses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#RetransformClasses) and [RedefineClasses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#RedefineClasses) functions of JVM TI.

If you are using JNI, you can use JVM TI functions as well. JVM TI works even without agents or special JVM arguments; it is available from any JNI context. E.g. how to get `jvmtiEnv*` from `JNIEnv*`:

```
JavaVM* vm;
(*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &vm);

jvmtiEnv* jvmti;
(*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void**)&jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_0);
```

Comment: I didn‘t know about JVM TI in JNI, thanks for that. But that‘s not what I need, because it is possible. The guy in this video did it like that: https://youtu.be/4Futai_P5gw The problem is that the video shows the result of the way I want to hook methods, but it doesn‘t explain anything.

Comment: @yungcxn The things are [not that simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530468/jni-get-java-methods-memory-address-with-getmethodid/59537294?noredirect=1#comment105245832_59530468). If you want to dig into the binary code of compiled Java methods, I suggest to start with `-XX:+PrintAssembly` JVM option - it will dump all the JIT compiled code with method names, addresses etc.

Comment: Ok... I understand. I will do it like you said, but how would you go on to find those method instances in memory? I don’t mind how hard it is, I have time :)

Comment: And do you have any resource of jvm ti with jni?